# Is it possible to increase the satchel size?

Tags: pokemon-legends-arceus

The default satchel size is 20 items, which fills up pretty quickly by having various pokeball types and picking up items in the overworld.

Is there anyway to increase the satchel size, or am I stuck having to manage my inventory wisely?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Yes, it's possible.**

After completing a few main quests, when you try to leave the Galaxy Hall, Bagin (the guard who stands next to the stairs from the 1st to the 2nd floor) will make an off-hand comment to come see him if you find yourself running out of satchel space.

From then on, you can talk to him to increase your satchel space by a single spot per purchase for an increasing amount of pokedollars.

The costs escalate fairly quickly though, so it seems like the intent of the developers is that you make frequent visits to the camps on the maps in order to clear up some inventory space.

The total amount of extra slots you can purchase seems to be 37, with the 37th slot costing 1 million pokedollars.

For reference, here's the price of each extra slot and the total amount you've paid by that point:

| Slot # | Cost | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ₽100 | ₽100 |
| 2 | ₽200 | ₽300 |
| 3 | ₽300 | ₽600 |
| 4 | ₽400 | ₽1,000 |
| 5 | ₽500 | ₽1,500 |
| 6 | ₽1,000 | ₽2,500 |
| 7 | ₽1,500 | ₽4,000 |
| 8 | ₽2,000 | ₽6,000 |
| 9 | ₽2,500 | ₽8,500 |
| 10 | ₽3,000 | ₽11,500 |
| 11 | ₽4,000 | ₽15,500 |
| 12 | ₽5,000 | ₽20,500 |
| 13 | ₽6,000 | ₽26,500 |
| 14 | ₽7,000 | ₽33,500 |
| 15 | ₽8,000 | ₽41,500 |
| 16 | ₽9,000 | ₽50,500 |
| 17 | ₽10,000 | ₽60,500 |
| 18 | ₽12,000 | ₽72,500 |
| 19 | ₽14,000 | ₽86,500 |
| 20 | ₽16,000 | ₽102,500 |
| 21 | ₽18,000 | ₽120,500 |
| 22 | ₽20,000 | ₽140,500 |
| 23 | ₽23,000 | ₽163,500 |
| 24 | ₽26,000 | ₽189,500 |
| 25 | ₽30,000 | ₽219,500 |
| 26 | ₽40,000 | ₽259,500 |
| 27 | ₽50,000 | ₽309,500 |
| 28 | ₽60,000 | ₽369,500 |
| 29 | ₽80,000 | ₽449,500 |
| 30 | ₽100,000 | ₽549,500 |
| 31 | ₽150,000 | ₽699,500 |
| 32 | ₽200,000 | ₽899,500 |
| 33 | ₽400,000 | ₽1,299,500 |
| 34 | ₽500,000 | ₽1,799,500 |
| 35 | ₽600,000 | ₽2,399,500 |
| 36 | ₽800,000 | ₽3,199,500 |
| 37 | ₽1,000,000 | ₽4,199,500 |

Source: a Gamerant.com article on the subject, corroborated by several other websites.

Comment: Dear Lord, is the ultimate satchel made of unicorn leather?

Comment: Wow. I guess I totally missed that dialogue with Bagin regarding to see him. Then again, I am notorious for skimming the dialogue in Pokemon games

Comment: @pinckerman Sounds like Galarian-Rapidash leather

Comment: @Wondercricket: Having played several hours of *Arceus*, I have noticed that its dialog is of significantly higher quality than (for example) *Sword* and *Shield* (where the same three NPCs repeat the same three plot points over and over again for the whole game, and then Rose infodumps everything else at the last second). *Arceus* does not seem to be doing that, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Kevin and now with mor puns.

Answer (score 11):

I was able to figure it out after taking to a lot of people in the village.

You can increase your satchel size by speaking to Bagin in the Galaxy Hall (first floor, right next to the stairs) at a cost.

Each purchase attributes to a single slot for your satchel. The first 5 purchases cost $100, 200, 300, $400, and $500 respectively. After the 5th purchases, the cost increases an additional $500 for each purchase: $1000, $1500, $2000, etc…

Comment: How much does each purchase expand the size?

Comment: @Malady updated my answer to include that

Comment: "Bagin" is the name of the character? A little on the nose there, but it is a clue in hindsight.

Comment: @BoogaRoo in Italian he is called Crescenzo, and it's clearly derived by "crescere" which means "to grow"